# get values of 2nd and 3rd element of a result set using the value of the 1st element

Tags: python, postgresql

```
acur.execute("Select id,firstname,lastname from tbl_emp")
tk = acur.fetchall()
```

result set is:

```
tk = [(1,'a','b'),(2,'c','d'),(3,'e','f')]
```

how to search this result set using the value of the first element?

say i search using 2, it will result to c and d.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking through the tuple:

```
>>> def search(_list, _value):
...     for item in _list:
...             if item[0] == _value:
...                     return item[1], item[2]
... 
>>> search(tk, 2)
('c', 'd')
>>> search(tk, 3)
('e', 'f')
>>> search(tk, 4)
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't filter it in the first place instead of getting all the records:

```
acur.execute("""
    SELECT 
        firstname, 
        lastname 
    FROM 
        tbl_emp 
    WHERE 
        id = %s""", (2, ))
firstname, lastname = acur.fetchone()
```